# SQLAlchemy password as asterisks causes login failure

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Here is my code:

```
class Read:
def engine(self, password):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:%s@localhost/DB" % password)
    print(engine)
    df = pd.read_sql_table("table_name", engine)
    print(df)
```

returns password as: `Engine(mysql+mysqlconnector://root:***@localhost/DB)`
With asterisks and that why doesn't work (I guess)

If I run it like:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:wherysecretpass@localhost/DB'
```

Works fine.

How do I get rid of those asterisks and send the real password?

Answer (score 2):

> How do i get rid of those asterisks and send real password?

When you `print(engine)` SQLAlchemy returns a string representation of the `engine` object *with the password obfuscated*. It sends the actual password to the server, but it displays asterisks in place of the password when you `print` (or write the string representation of the Engine object to a log file).

So, your problem is with the password itself, not SQLAlchemy's representation of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the unobfuscated url, you can pass `hide_password=False` the [URL.render_as_string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.render_as_string) method:

```py
print(engine.url.render_as_string(hide_password=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the full connection string using `SQLAlchemy`, you can use the following code:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

url = URL.create(
    drivername='postgresql',
    username='root',
    password='secret',
    host='localhost',
    port=5432,
    database='dbname',
).render_as_string(hide_password=False)
```